# How to write API call using axios in Vue.js app?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, axios

I have Vue.js app on frontend and C# on backend. I need to write API call from frontend using axios. The code looks as following:

**BACKEND:**

```c#
public class FbProductController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Add new connection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="values">json string with an object</param>
    /// <returns>New connection object</returns>
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("~/api/async/fbProduct/insertProductReqtype")]
    public IHttpActionResult InsertProductReqtype(string values)
    {
        var newProductReqtype = EntityFactory.Create<IFbProductReqtype>();
        JsonConvert.PopulateObject(values, newProductReqtype);

        string errMessage = ValidateNewProductReqtype(newProductReqtype);
        if (errMessage != null)
            return BadRequest(errMessage);

        newProductReqtype.Save();

        return Ok(newProductReqtype);
    }
```

**FRONTEND:**

```js
async onOk(obj) {
    if (!obj.ID) {
        const newProductReqtype = {
            Fb_productId: `${productId}`,
            Fb_reqTypeId: '${reqtypeId}',
            Type_name: `${typeName}`
        };
        const result = await this.$gpbApi.catalogProducts.insertProductReqtype(JSON.stringify(newProductReqtype));
}
```

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export async function insertProductReqtype(newProductReqtype) {
    if (newProductReqtype == null) return;

    const { data } = await axios.post('api/async/fbProduct/insertProductReqtype', newProductReqtype );

    return data;
}
```

But, I've got an error:

```
Message: "The HTTP resource matching the request URI could not be found \"http://localhost/SlxClient/api/async/fbProduct/insertProductReqtype\"."
MessageDetail: "The action corresponding to the request could not be found on the controller \"FbProduct\"."
```

Comment: 1) Be careful using a relative URL in Axios. It will be relative to the current page. 2) Don't stringify the data, let Axios do that for you and in the process it will also set the correct content-type

Comment: @Phil: We've found the solution by change the backend a little bit. We used object as parameter instead of string. Thanks for your help.